# How to set WorkTime of assignment by days using PSI?

Tags: c#, psi

I need to create assignments on tasks and set different work time for every day for example:
task - "Building of house"
assignment - "Andrew" - monday=4hours | tuesday = 3 hours | wednesday = 7hours
assignment - "Mike" - monday=5hours | tuesday = 7hours | wednesday = 2hours

I tryed to use SvcResourcePlan, but i think that it's not what i need because i can add only one row (project_uid, resource_uid).Also i know that this information contains in  the DB table named MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay_UserView. So how can i make it?

also i tryed this code, but there are no any changes in my project, or any exceptions

```
string query = 
                @"<Changes>
                <Proj ID=""25F26CD8-7967-E511-80BE-00155D020E00"">
                           <Assn ID=""CB71C932-5668-E511-80BE-00155D020E00"" ResID=""BB0B57E9-8167-E511-80BE-00155D020E00"">
                               <PeriodChange PID=""251658246"" Start=""2015-10-07T09:00:00"" End=""2015-10-07T18:00:00"">480000</PeriodChange>
                           </Assn>
                </Proj>
               </Changes>";
            stContext.UpdateStatus(query);
            stContext.SubmitStatusForResource(new Guid("BB0B57E9-8167-E511-80BE-00155D020E00"), new Guid[] { new Guid("CB71C932-5668-E511-80BE-00155D020E00") }, "111sdfsdfsdf");
            stContext.SubmitStatus(new Guid[] { new Guid("CB71C932-5668-E511-80BE-00155D020E00") }, "Updated work");
            projectSvc.QueuePublish(Guid.NewGuid(), new Guid("25f26cd8-7967-e511-80be-00155d020e00"), true, "rr");
```

Comment: Show what you have tried, what worked, what didn't, etc.

Comment: i tryed this example https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg176786.aspx
but as i said i can add row (res_UID, proj_UID) only once. There is no any field named Task_UID

Comment: i found SvcStatusing.StatusingTimephasedActualsDataSet, but i can't find method in SvcStatusing, which updates this information